Legality of randomized price for product
Suppose I sell a product online, except instead of charging $1, I charge $100 and then with 99% probability give the money back. Would this be legal or would it be considered an unlicensed lottery or something like that?
I'm interested in laws in the US and/or Canada.

That would be a randomized rebate, not a randomized price.

@user71659 alternatively a payment of $100 could be authorized and only captured with probability 1%. I don't know if that makes a difference.

I'm fairly sure there are/ were cases of items for sale online being priced differently depending on the person/device trying to make the purchase. That seems to be legal, so showing different random prices to different people should be fine as well.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102276/does-consumer-protection-cover-price-changes-at-point-of-sale/102282#102282 Usually, you will be required to state the exact price you charge e.g. the customer's credit card with before the transaction can be completed. Since the price is a necessary part of a sales contract, a sale contract without an agreed price will probably be considred void.

@quarague The difference is if you show a random/different price to somebody prior to purchase, they can walk away without spending anything. OP doesn't want that, they want to force a wager by randomizing the rebate, which is like gambling: you don't get to to roll before you place a bet.

Might be a cash back offer, might be an (il)legal sweepstakes
From the description, it tends more towards the latter than the former due to the random nature of the “prize”.  Whether a sweepstakes is illegal or not and what conditions make it one or the other depends on local law.

So you claim the value of an item is $1. Obviously I won’t hand over $100 for a $1 item, because I wouldn’t trust you enough. And even if a trusted you, I wouldn’t risk having to pay $100 for an item worth $1.
Now if I did this, you must be aware that in many countries I have the right to return the item for a full refund. So if I was the person chosen to pay $100, you won’t actually get any money because you have to refund me.

This doesn’t answer the OP’s question about legality.
